# Cakephp Blog add Category and article at same time

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I want to extend the cakephp 3.x blog tutorial.

I want to Have the ADD ARTICLE FORM (articles/add) let you select a category OR create a new category and link it to the new article.

If have this in articles/add.ctp:

```
<h1>Add Article</h1>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create($article);
    echo $this->Form->input('title');
    echo $this->Form->input('category_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('body', ['rows' => '3']);
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Save Article'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

And this in the ArticlesContoller.php for add

```
    public function add()
    {
    $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if($this->request->data['category_id']==""){




   $this->Categories->add($category );



        }

        $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data);
        // Added this line
        $article->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        // You could also do the following
        //$newData = ['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')];
        //$article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $newData);
        if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
    }
    $this->set('article', $article);

        $categories = $this->Articles->Categories->find('treeList');
        $this->set(compact('categories'));

    // Just added the categories list to be able to choose
    // one category for an article
   // $categories = $this->Articles->Categories->find('treeList');
    //$this->set(compact('categories'));
    }
```

But I get an "unknown method" error On Categories->add

How do i add the category at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mean that you haven't method in table Categories.
You mush create method in src/Model/Table/CategoriesTable.php like this:

```
public function add($data)
{
$category = new Entity();
$category->...
//add columns what you need to save in table
if($this->save($category)){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}
```